# Каким требованиям должна соответствовать структура при использовании на границе общения с DLL?

Tags: c++, c, pod

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким требованиям должна соответствовать структура для того, чтобы ее можно было использовать для общения через границу `DLL` (при использовании `export "C"`)?

Для проверки структуры я могу использовать следующие шаблоны:

```
std::is_pod<>
std::is_standard_layout<>
std::is_trivial<>
```

Я не совсем понимаю, каким требованиям должна соответствовать такая структура.

Достаточно ли ей иметь стандартную компоновку (`is_standard_layout`)?

Может быть, она обязательно должна быть тривиальной (`is_trivial`)?

Или же, она должна быть именно простой (`is_pod`)?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но нельзя передавать структуры туда-сюда, можно в длл передать указатель на память, внутри длл его разыменовать и заполнить структуру данными, соотв. структура должна быть выровнена и не содержать с++ типов (строки, вектора)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, можно и так, и так. Но даже если передавать указатель на структуру, нужно, чтобы структура по обе стороны интерфейса выглядела в памяти одинаково.

Comment: Любую структуру можно использовать для общения через границу dll. Другое дело если необходимо обеспечить возможно взаимодействия модулей, написанных на разных языках и / или собранными разными компиляторами.